# Can Nokogiri treat unordered lists as paragraphs?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri as part of my Ruby on Rails docx generator and I'm running into a little of a problem. I'm using Nokogiri to parse through each paragraph in my application and do some things to all of the text that has HTML tags around it.

However, be fore I'm iterating through each paragraph, I'm missing the unordered lists. Here's what the text editor produces in my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p><strong>Just testing <em>something</em> out </strong>over here.</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph that contains bullets though:</p>
<ul>
<li>One thing here.</li>
<li>Another thing here</li>
</ul>
<p>Some more text.</p>
</body></html>
```

I'm using this ruby code to basically iterate through the paragraphs:

```
# test = the HTML above that I just pasted
html = Nokogiri::HTML(test)
html.xpath("//p").each do |paragraph|
  # some code here that converts HTML -> WordML
end
```

As a result, that code only catches this:

```
# output of html.xpath("//p")
<p><strong>Just testing <em>something</em> out </strong>over here.</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph that contains bullets though:</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
```

I need to somehow capture the `p` tag and treat the `ul` tag as if it was inside of a `p` tag as well. Otherwise, I'll only be converting the HTML that's inside of the paragraph tags to WordML and the unordered lists.

So I was able to get half way there -- I can use `html.xpath("//p | //ul")` to get me there, but the problem comes when i have nested `ul` tags. So for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p><strong>Just testing <em>something</em> out </strong>over here.</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph that contains bullets though:</p>
<ul>
<li>One thing here.<ul><li>One more thing</li></ul>
</li>
<li>Another thing here</li>
</ul>
<p><br></p>
<ul><li>nothing</li></ul>
<p>Some more text.</p>
</body></html>
```

becomes

```
<p><strong>Just testing <em>something</em> out </strong>over here.</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph that contains bullets though:</p>
<ul>
<li>One thing here.<ul><li>One more thing</li></ul>
</li>
<li>Another thing here</li>
</ul>
<ul><li>One more thing</li></ul>
<p><br></p>
<ul><li>nothing</li></ul>
<p>Some more text.</p>
```

which, as you can see, contains the nested `ul` data twice (because it's a nested `ul` tag I assume)

Comment: Please don't use "Update" or "Edit" tags in your text. Instead, incorporate the new information into the body where it should have been in the first place. Also, note that Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum. Every question stands alone, so asking one thing, then modifying it and asking another breaks the way SO works. If there are two very related questions then it's OK to ask them in the initial question, but be very careful, and sensitive to, modifying questions. SO isn't just about answering your question, it's about answering the question for future searchers too.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking, in addition to the code in question, we need to see the minimal input that demonstrates the problem, and the expected output. Currently we have to imagine what you're trying to get.

Comment: Sounds great. I'll just open up another question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out just toying around with some random syntax. I was able to solve this by using 
`html.xpath("//p", "//ul")` in the example above.

Comment: Nokogiri can't treat the `<ul>` tags as if they're inside `<p>`, because they're not. You could make them be inside with Nokogiri, then continue processing the document; That'd technically be an invalid document but HTML is "liberal" about that stuff. Using an array of selectors works, though it'll return all the `<p>` tags, then all the `<ul>` tags, without respecting their original order.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I believe my original question may have been a little misleading, treating it as `p`. I should have stated that I wanted it to split up the text like `p` was as well. However, `html.xpath("//p", "//u")` does exactly that and solved the issue.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do two different things:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<ul>
<li>l1</li>
</ul>
<p>p3</p>
</body></html>
EOT

doc.search('p', 'ul').map(&:to_html)
# => ["<p>p1</p>", "<p>p2</p>", "<p>p3</p>", "<ul>\n<li>l1</li>\n</ul>"]
```

This uses CSS, which finds either type of node, first looking for `<p>` tags, *then* looking for `<ul>` tags.

Using XPath:

```
doc.search('//p | //ul').map(&:to_html)
# => ["<p>p1</p>", "<p>p2</p>", "<ul>\n<li>l1</li>\n</ul>", "<p>p3</p>"]
```

This looks for either `<p>` or `<ul>` tags, not one *then* the other.

Comment: Thanks. My answer that I provided actually didn't do it in order, but using your example does. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hey, quick question. For some reason this is getting really bad when it comes to nested unordered lists. So for example `<ul><li>testing<ul><li>another test</li></ul></li></ul>` gets a little screwed up. While it breaks down the main `ul` it starts appending the nested `ul` at the end of the first `ul` as if it's a completely separate list.